# Comparing two ArrayList using containsAll()

Tags: java, arraylist, contains

Can someone please help me with this?

I have two ArrayLists.

`array1` contains:

> [3 Avocados, 3 Tomatoes, 1 Teaspoon of Salt, 1/2 Cup Diced onion]

`array2` contains:

> [Avocados, Tomatoes]

I'm trying to use `array1.containsAll(array2)` but it's returning `false` because of the "3"s in front of Avocados and Tomatoes in `array1`.

Thank you!

Comment: Okay, and what do you want it to do? Why is it not a `Map`?

Comment: Hint: A couple of nested for-loops and a couple pass/fail/bail flags would get the job done.

Comment: This is what Guava `Multiset`s are for. Though on second thought, not for 1/2 cups of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead. HashMaps contain a set of keys and values instead of one value like array lists. In this case, you should have the names of the ingredients as the key and the amount as the value. HashMap, however, does not have a containsAll method, but you can get a set of the keys(ingredients) and then call [Set.containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
HashMap<String, Integer> array1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<String>();
array1.put("Avocados", 3);
array1.put("Tomatoes", 3);
//etc.
array1.keySet().containsAll(array2);
```

Comment: You can do `array1.keySet().containsAll(array2)`, but, you should also rename `array1` to `recipe` or something.

Comment: @rolfl Very true. I forgot that `Set` had a `containsAll`. And I just left the variable names the same to try to make it clear, but it did feel strange naming a map array1.

Comment: On second thought, you may be better off with a `HashMap<String, String>` if you don't want all of your amounts to be numbers(1/2 Cup). Same concept though.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting HashMap. One last question! I don't want to manually add in array1.put(avocados), array1.put(tomatoes), etc. I want to loop it so I can put n number of keys and values. Is there a way I can parse the string and integer out of my original array1 to put into the HashMap?

Comment: How were you filling the original `ArrayList`? You can probably do it the same way.

Comment: I split the string and stored it as an array. And turned the array into an ArrayList. Because if I split the string and store directly into ArrayList, it just take the entire string in as one value. I will have to play around with it to see how I can split the integer and string. Thanks again for the HashMap suggestion. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

containsAll() checks for object equality using the method equals().

if you want to compare strings like that you should use String#contains method and some loops

or you could create your own class with description and quantity attributes, and overwrite the equals() method

It depends on what you want to do